# Count number of sublists with a total not greater than a given max

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, combinatorics

Suppose I have a list of positive integers:

```
data={1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10, 10, 12, 16, 23}
```

I want to count the number of subsets up to length *t* (including an empty set) whose total doesn't exceed the value *t*.

The naive approach would be:

```
sumZaehl[t_, data_] :=
  Length@Select[Total /@ Subsets[data, t], # <= t &]
```

But this would not work for larger list, because of the rapidly increasing number of subsets.
I have an iterative method which works for larger list too:

```
sumZaehlIter[t_, data_] :=
Module[{n = Length[data], v, d, i, j},
  For[i = 0, i <= t, i++, v[i] = 1];
  For[i = 1, i <= n, i++,
    d = data[[i]];
    For[j = t, j >= d, j--, 
       v[j] = v[j] + v[j - d]; 
 ]];
v[t]]
```

Is there a functional way to realize this?

Comment: I figure that the sublists with a total not greater than 3 are following six: {{},{1},{2},{3},{1,1},{1,2}}. Yet both your `sumZaehlIter[3,data]` and Leonid's `v[3,data]` return 10. What are the other four sublists with a total not greater than 3?

Comment: @David, I think (with multiplicities of some elements), there are two additional occurences of `{3}` and one additional occurence for each of `{1}` and `{2,1}`.

Comment: @kguler Interesting. So it has nothing to do with the order of the elements within a sublist?

Comment: @David, yes; so the complete collection is {{},{1},{1},{2},{3},{3},{3},{1,1},{1,2},{1,2}}.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not really the same algorithm, but

```
ClearAll[v];
v[t_, data_] :=
   Block[{v},
     v[_?Negative, _] := 0;
     v[_, 0] := 1;
     v[tl_, n_] := v[tl, n] =
        v[tl - data[[n]], n - 1] + v[tl, n - 1];
     v[t, Length[data]]
   ];
```

You may need to increase the `$RecursionLimit` for larger lists.

Comment: the iterative Module works quite well but I'm interested in functional. With the "naive" way I get errors "Subset::toomany and "must be a machine integer". Why "a machine integer"

Comment: @Peter Your iterative algorithm uses a lot of mutable state. While you probably can achieve the same with the functional constructs, I suspect that the direct translation of it into functional would be either inefficient or resulting in a thin functional facade over the essentially procedural core. The algorithm I posted above has the same underlying idea as yours, but IMO is a functional version of it (although not a direct translation), using recursion and memoization. A similar situation happens e.g. with the longest common sequence algorithm.

Comment: That's beautiful. +1

Comment: Nice solution! +1

Comment: @Pillsy, Mr.Wizard Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Ah, came across this from the "related" bar, time for a necro :-}

Here's a direct and fast one-liner:

```
numSST[t_, s_] := Block[{p = Normal[Times @@ (1 + x^s) + O[x]^(t + 1)], x = 1}, p];
```

Comment: @ciao...I really enjoyed this one-liner...

Comment: Nice use of `O[]`. ;)